# jQuery UI autocomplete (combobox): how to fill it with the result of an AJAX request?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is it possible to work with [combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) as with usual [jquery-ui ajax autocomplete field](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)?

What I need?

I want there will be some default options and when user try to put any letters it must connect to the server to find requested information (as usual remote json autocomplete).

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Does it matter if the underlying element is a `select` (like it is in the combobox example)?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a heavily modified version of the jQueryUI example ([gist](https://gist.github.com/1407447)):

```
$.widget("ui.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
        var _self = this
            , options = $.extend({}, this.options, {
            minLength: 0,
            source: function(request, response) {
                if (!request.term.length) {
                    response(_self.options.initialValues);
                } else {
                    if (typeof _self.options.source === "function") {
                        _self.options.source(request, response);
                    } else if (typeof _self.options.source === "string") {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: _self.options.source,
                            data: request,
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(data, status) {
                                response(data);
                            },
                            error: function() {
                                response([]);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        this.element.autocomplete(options);

        this.button = $("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>")
            .attr("tabIndex", -1)
            .attr("title", "Show All Items")
            .insertAfter(this.element)
            .button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                },
            text: false
            })
            .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
            .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")
            .click(function() {
                if (_self.element.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                    _self.element.autocomplete("close");
                    return;
                }
                _self.element.autocomplete("search", "");
                _self.element.focus();
        });
    }
});
```

**Usage:**

```
$("input_element_selector").combobox({
    initialValues: ['array', 'of', 'values'],
    source: /* <-- function or string performing remote search */,
    /* any other valid autocomplete options */
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Jpqa8/

The widget uses the supplied `initialValues` array as the source when the length of the search is "0" (this happens when the user clicks the dropdown button).

Supply a `source` parameter (function or string) that performs the remote search. You can also use any other options you would usually use with the autocomplete widget.

Comment: The only question is how to do initial values be an object, not array? For example: `{'1':'array', '6':'of', '9':'values'}`. Because when user choose any initial value it must return it's id value (like usual select).

Comment: Looks like I didn't understand your clarifying question (my poor English). Sorry...

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: You can provide an array like this: `[{ 'label': 'array', 'value': '1'}, {'label': 'of', 'value': '6'}, {'label': 'values', 'value': '9'}]`

Comment: The only thing is when I choose some initial value, it automatically replaces it with it's digit... http://jsfiddle.net/eeMfN/  (What I want: initial values are the most popular cities in some country)

Comment: Ah I see. Well you can make it so that when you select an item it shows the `label` and not the `value`, but then the `value` won't be POSTed correctly...

Comment: have any interesting ideas about that?:)))

Comment: You could update a hidden field with the `value` property on `select`: `select: function(event,ui) { this.value = ui.item.label; $("hidden_field_selector").val(ui.item.value); }`

Comment: And how to make when I select an item it shows the label, not the value?? (sorry, for such maybe stupid questions - I'm truly new in js). Thanks!